# Visual Basic: How to only accept 0 and 1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, input

sorry to be a bother but I have been working on a binary addition code for some time now and I have nearly gotten it finished. However, there is still a minor problem that I have been struggling to fix involving valid input.
In this code, it should find the length of the binary input and convert each character to denary before adding them up. If an input that is not 0 or 1 is entered then it should reject the input and tell the user to restart the code.
 The problem I am having is that when erroneous data is entered, the code will simply crash instead of going to the line of code where it will tell the user that it is invalid input. Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

Note: I have repeated this code twice for both binary values being entered.

The section of the program where I believe the error is currently looks like this:

```
 Y is what I am using to convert the value to denary so I can add binary values together in denary form. [integer]
 binarya is the input value. [string]
 chart is the current character being converted. [integer]
 current is the current character converted to denary. [integer]
 denarya is the denary value of binarya. [integer]



Y = 1
binarya = console.readline
Len(binarya)
For i = Len(binarya) to 1 step -1
chart = Mid(binarya, i, 1)
If chart <> "1" and chart <> "0"  then
Console.readline("This is not valid BINARY input, restart the code!")
Console.readline
End if
current = chart * 1 * Y
denarya = denarya + current
Y = Y * 2
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the message, not read it. Also, you should return after you read it.

```
Y = 1
binarya = console.readline
Len(binarya)
For i = Len(binarya) to 1 step -1
    chart = Mid(binarya, i, 1)
    If chart <> "1" and chart <> "0"  then
        Console.WriteLine("This is not valid BINARY input, restart the code!")
        Console.ReadLine
        Return
    End if
    current = chart * 1 * Y
    denarya = denarya + current
    Y = Y * 2
Next
```